# Fox Calculus/Fox Derivative

Tags: group-theory

Is there a way to compute the Fox derivative in Mathematica?

I know there are some [methods to do it in Sage](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/free_group.html), but I'd like to use Mathematica instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: (1.)  It would be a good idea to, at the very least, post a reference link explaining the Fox derivative, so users don't have to search themselves and possibly guess.  (2.)  A quick search doesn't come up with anything obvious (I could be wrong about this), but you can certainly implement it yourself.  Perhaps you could edit the question with a bit more about the problem you want to solve, and hopefully include some attempt to implement it in Mathematica yourself.

Comment: related? http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6139

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_derivative

Comment: The Fox derivative is a remarkably useful tool, for example, for extracting information about Alexander modules of 3-manifolds from finite presentations of their fundamental group.  I too would love to know an elegant way of implementing them in Mathematica.